# How to convert the output of one-class SVM to probability estimates using the Platt Scaling approach?

Tags: svm, probability, scaling, libsvm

I have implemented one-class SVM using the `libsvm`. However, due to the fact that it is one-class SVM I can't use the method `svm_predict_probability`, but only `svm_predict_values`, which means I can only get the decision values for each instance of my testing set.

However, I want to have the probability estimates of each instance. I read a lot about this and according to literature the best way to do this is by using the idea of Platt Scaling. The problem is that I don't know how to implement such Platt Scaling.

I would appreciate any help with implementing it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You will need to train an additional logistic regression model using outputs of SVM.  http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html